# Limiting distribution of harmonic sample means of i.i.d. $U(0,1)$s after appropriate scaling.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables which follow the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Denote
$$M_n=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n},\;H_n=\frac{n}{\frac{1}{X_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{X_n}}.$$
By Strong Law of Large Numbers we know $M_n\to\frac{1}{2},H_n\to0$ almost surely. Note for $p\geq1$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}M_n^p\leq\mathbb{E}\frac{X_1^p+\cdots+X_n^p}{n}=\mathbb{E}X_1^p,$$
thus $M_n$ is bounded in $L^p$ for any $p\geq1$. Note $H_n\leq M_n$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we know $\{H_n,M_n|n\geq1\}$ is bounded in $L^p$. Hence we know for any $r\geq1$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}M_n^r\to2^{-r},\mathbb{E}H_n^r\to0.$$
Now I want to find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ so that $a_nH_n$ converges (in distribution) to some nonzero distribution, but I don't know how to deal with it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272528/1-s2.0-S0196885800X0067X/1-s2.0-S019688580300023X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBkaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCDGTnDpoBpfCPac6LqGApONFL1Yofg2uOoCcg7aGv4AwIhALbOP61TlKcrFYg93hM3NeygoacAW5%2BxQe6x5I7vW%2BzhKrMFCBIQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgxQCptNUgfJD3QhYxUqkAVBmmMKuzkKaQ0t6gJeQUNDaZN%2BdiH3kNUAmVZK5BMOOX8gM61jQkB6P%2BVTFjeiAoKaLCNODbRznnLB1rv7lFwU0GrqW5prPe%2FXEv3fGYN2S%2FFerMEnl9yab2SClWPzgRe1Eh5DyqaCZKz5MFJWce1lUPEIDKX%2BS7fQa89b28S7e0OiXzwTX2Q5Eb1%2Blx0HQEBsNFPfrfR4GhwCzOeOJnBzwybCCYzMQ9b50FFkUaz2JEniSmFnVDIoLHe3w%2F2VEuMqu%2BOF9%2F1MnJ9Uw86qa1RSJQ%2BdWwMf4F0k9ygWz1%2BgqERsb%2FhePIplT53p3%2FgQa71Y7AY8CA%2BxffG8%2B6OSlHzmMDyFVJBSJNw43byg%2FF8TFbX8yMSVawCsJ%2FuzHEwSbG7oDtP1QxnKfMQ48%2B26HErXK9u4hZ1nwj0yJcr2d0ggcTs%2FArgK2JMfo8HGO%2FepzP0wZdKke%2BzpjxnKfEAX0k1kYBmBxJJIN4kZ9yxVC4LAQReaPv%2BTfdf09JIpc9E9Y8gE%2Bz2lscO2HVYnENegbFlPjDSwbmrl%2FryeV1z%2BFAqqpUXEhgyRWt5A3vSofjZhmwyDzkhUd0Hk%2FC6GQnd%2FnZKLSExoJXKvEXx%2F6mz%2BNY9ceZE7ysNcMi0V6rfkTag%2FI2YtzhxQel0LdA7OkKD6mY2aPSxitO4GZDVnDeKC9ejNmXn6iMLP26V3p9ymx1346JX6yBfJIdVVHvh1zOCU5gJEohtvanzgXvmbDnvUFXVPkm0ROYWQgCDOgOlGP1bQRoQ67rfkCkaBpDJ8VlsfaDq3I5D%2F4nMNOszGfXUxiLsHD%2BGb6zxuYcITtheSfhxMuAiCcd8Dfp400Pz9XFPICzr9R%2Fb99Ma11qW4G1opcoIwYzD6%2FoCvBjqwAQjbjwEzbUJQqkt3yB2hws6%2F561eaUJPN%2BUegPFZ1VY1jjeKC0lORvxW4vT0Cd%2FtRcu8OoQGDA1bBJeRMyYTNlefUGsgvjWDfpwCzxe8AD23TjF2l6I6tmhUakTe4QukR%2BF50b6viOmxMmbanJ%2BersESpXQ212IrTAQYsm7t2REVcVGtG36wGaXNw2aY9ISmgz9vp8UBCNenQDXZHJkCoBymuXsFOijIRZ2OqEnsjkoK&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240229T085922Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYY45IMF5H%2F20240229%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=21a7f0b213085d20c952ec2a5cb98b3068f3bfd8fb69f569b71657a4c875b729&hash=e85af2c990f4da0c8daa7be9aa741dbc597445b2771ed5497f25b5144c8dbb6f&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S019688580300023X&tid=spdf-f09c8858-0b12-48aa-b789-e4709e9c3c21&sid=a58414416b2d4242805972321c7221a5b538gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1c165c500001045a0451&rr=85cfb5f61d3dd722&cc=fr), theorem 2.5, we have:
$$H_n \cdot \ln^2(n)-\ln(n) \xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{\mathcal D} X$$
where $X$ has the density function $f_X(x) = g(-x)$ with $g$ defined by the formula $(12)$.